# Foreign Keys in Entity Framework 7 (rc1)

Tags: entity-framework, win-universal-app, entity-framework-core

I have a `UserProfile` object model and a `Friendship` model which links 2 user profiles together and keeps track of some friendship meta data such as `friends since` and a rank. On login, I insert the users as well as the friendships (I can see it all in the db). When I load a user, though, I have `null` in `Friendships`. I'm a little lost as to how this all is supposed to work. A user can have many friends and be a friend to other users.

Here's the `UserProfile` object:

```
public class UserProfile {
    [DataMember (Name = "uid"), Key]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
[DataMember (Name = "un")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [DataMember (Name = "em")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataMember (Name = "fn")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public List<Friendship> Friendships { get; set; }
}
```

and the `Friendship` object (If I can get rid of the `User` in here, I won't miss it):

```
public class Friendship
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public UserProfile User { get; set; }
    public string FriendId { get; set; }
    public UserProfile Friend { get; set; }
    public ulong Since { get; set; }
    public uint Rank { get; set; }
}
```

... and my `OnModelCreating` function:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating (ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile> ().HasIndex (p => p.Username);
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile> ().HasIndex (p => p.Email);
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile> ().HasMany (p => p.Friendships)
                .WithOne (f => f.Friend)
                .HasForeignKey (f => new { f.UserId, f.FriendId })
                .OnDelete(Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship> ().HasKey (k=> new {k.UserId, k.FriendId});
    modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship> ().HasOne (u => u.User)
            .WithMany (u => u.Friendships)
            .HasForeignKey (fs => fs.UserId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship> ().HasOne (u => u.Friend)
            .WithMany (f => f.Friendships)
            .HasForeignKey (fs => fs.FriendId);
}
```

I expect that I should be able to get the `UserProfile` of the logged in user (let's call this `me`), wrap the `UserProfile`s of their friends inside `Friendship` objects and add each to the user's `Friendships`, and then store `me` in the `DbContext`. However, doing this leads to the following error message:

> The instance of entity type 'Friendship' cannot be tracked because
>   another instance of this type with the same key is already being
>   tracked. For new entities consider using an IIdentityGenerator to
>   generate unique key values.

This sounds like one of those error messages that say one thing and actually mean something else. Because at the time of this insert the sqlite db is ***empty***. So what exactly is being tracked if this is the first time it's seeing this data?

The only way so far that I've been able to store items has been to store the `UserProfile`s separately followed by the `Friendship` objects linking them.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Firstly, I need to confirm this code `(p => p.Username)` is actually `(p => p.UserId) `, right? Secondly, I want to confirm that your requirements just is when me login I can see my profile and in my profile  I had a FriendShip list, click one friend will lead to this friend's profile. Thirdly, what does  "store me in the DataContext" mean?

Comment: @sunteen 1. No, there actually is a `Username` field that I missed initially. I've updated the question. 2. Yes, when the user logs in they can see their profile as well as their list of friends. 3. The DataContext is backed by some sort of storage (in my case sqlite). So I really just mean *stored in db*.

Comment: It's not actually `DataContext`, it's `DbContext` I was so sure I didn't bother checking.

Comment: I'm trying to build a project as you describe. But they're a little much. The code you have uploaded with no error.Could  you please upload your project to github or onedriver directly? And the flow is :1.Login the user and insert the friends  into Userprofile table.2.Load user,find the user from table UserProfile and find his friends in FriendShip all by userID.

Comment: There's a lot of IP in the code and the server isn't public. I can't post the rest of the code here. Sorry.